# How to remove the schema name from tables for use with set search_path in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL 9.5.4

In changing around the names on my schemas in the database, PostgreSQL added the schema name to each of the tables in the schema.

That is, *companies* became *public.companies*. Now in setting the default path, with

```
ALTER DATABASE chaos SET search_path TO public;
```

select * from companies fails.  However, select * from public.companies works.

What can be done to either remove the unwanted schema name from its tables, and/or establish a search_path that respects the simple

```
select * from companies
```

TIA

Edit:
The opening database definition does a "set search_path to public". However, when doing a "show search_path" in a PgAdmin III query session, "nova" is returned with "show search_path" -- is the problem with PgAdmin ?

Comment: `SET search_path TO public;`

Comment: What does `show search_path;` return? If it's set for the user you're connected as it will override the database default.

Comment: @teppic "show search_path" shows "nova" --the name prior to renaming the schema's.  "Alter database chaos set search_path to public" seems not to be respected??

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev  "Set search_path to public:" worked -- but is it permanent?

Comment: Use `alter role <myuser> set search_path to public;` to make it permanent.

Comment: @teppic Great! "alter role postgres set search_path to public;" -- worked! That will save me alot of time. :)

Comment: After `ALTER DATABASE chaos SET ...` you should to reconnect to get the effect.